# Can't sort unordered_set

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an unordered_set of a class `ActiveStatusEffect` The set is declared as follows:

```
boost::unordered_set<StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect> ActiveStatusEffects;
```

ActiveStatusEffect is defined as follows:

```
class ActiveStatusEffect
    {
    public:
        StatusEffect* effect;
        int ReminaingTurns;
        bool operator<(const ActiveStatusEffect& ase) const
        {
            return *effect < *ase.effect;
        }
        bool operator>(const ActiveStatusEffect& ase) const
        {
            return *effect > *ase.effect;
        }
        bool operator==(const ActiveStatusEffect& ase) const
        {
            return *effect == *ase.effect;
        }
        bool operator!=(const ActiveStatusEffect& ase) const
        {
            return !((*this) == ase);
        }
    };
```

The comparison between StatusEffect's is a comparison between a unique integer assinged to each instance of a status effect.

However, if I try to sort the effects like follows:

```
std::sort(statusSet.begin(), statusSet.end(), [](StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect const &se1, StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect const &se2){return se1.effect->GetPriority() < se2.effect->GetPriority();});
```

I get many errors in the algorithm header file such as

> Error 198 error C2784:
>   '_Base1::difference_type std::operator
>   -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2>
>   &)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const
>   std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from
>   'boost::unordered_detail::hash_const_iterator'   c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\algorithm 3806
>
> Error 199 error C2784:
>   '_Base1::difference_type std::operator
>   -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2>
>   &)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const
>   std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from
>   'boost::unordered_detail::hash_const_iterator'   c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\algorithm 3806

Why am I not able to sort the set? I'm quite certain this is something about unordered_set as removing attempts to sort or changing it to a vector does not generate errors.

Comment: If the set is **unordered** how would you sort (e.g. **order**) it?

Comment: Somehow this really made me laugh... must be the time it's 2 am and im on SO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boost::unordered_set<Foo> a;
a.insert(...);
...

std::set<Foo> b(a.begin(), a.end());

std::set<Foo> c;
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::inserter(c, c.end());
```

Voilà, a sorted set.

Answer (score 7):

`unordered_set` doesn't have non-const iterators, because if you could mutate the item pointed to by an iterator you could violate the invariants of the set (uniqueness among others). Additionally if you sorted an unordered_set you would no longer be able to look up the item in the container anymore (assuming it works by hash).

If you *really* want to sort the set of items, you'll need to copy it into a `vector` first and then sort that. But in that case have you considered if `unordered_set` is the right container for you in the first place? What about using a normal `set` which *is* ordered at the expense of lookups being slower.