# c++ How does unordered_set prevent from begin "sorted" from syntax level?

Tags: c++, sorting, compilation, set, unordered-set

I'm just curious if I apply "std::sort" on unordered_set, what will happen. Does STL design protect unordered_set from using std::sort on it, if yes, how is it achieved from syntax level?

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>
using namespace std;
struct E{
    char vertex;
    size_t distance;
    E(char v, size_t d):vertex(v),distance(d){}
    E(const E& e):vertex(e.vertex),distance(e.distance){}
    E& operator=(const E& e){
        vertex = e.vertex;
        distance = e.distance;
        return *this;
    }
};
template<>
struct std::hash<E> {
    std::size_t operator()(const E& e) const {
        return e.vertex;
    }
};  
using edgeSet=unordered_set<E>;
int main(){ 
    edgeSet U;
    while(!U.empty()){
        sort(U.begin(),U.end());//ERROR!
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

As I expected, it gives a lot of error information below:

```
g++ m.cpp -std=c++11
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                from m.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<E, true, true>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4836:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<E, true, true>]’
m.cpp:26:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1969:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::__detail::_Node_iterator<E, true, true>’ and ‘std::__detail::_Node_iterator<E, true, true>’)
    std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Well, could you help to explain how STL protect this "sort", I don't quite get the meaning of this error information, what does the information indicate? Just want the learn the skill. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It makes no sense to sort a hashing container. Why would you want that?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957473/1413395) specifically.

Comment: Besides making no sense, it's all about *iterators*: [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) have [*forward iterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) when [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires [*random access iterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). That's why you get the errors.